# Django model filefield clear checkbox function is not working with using clean method of field

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-rest-framework, django-views

Clear checkbox for filefield like (image) is not working when i am using the clean function for the field

[image]

clean function:

```
 def clean_image(self):
    #file = self.cleaned_data['image']
    file = self.cleaned_data['image']
    if file:
        if not os.path.splitext(file.name)[1] in [".jpg", ".png"]:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                _("Doesn't have proper extension"))
        return file
```

But if i remove the clean function the checkbox clear functionality is working fine, is there any conflict in using these two methods

Comment: What do you use for clearing the checkbox?

Comment: to remove the currently used image name from the db , is this a default option in django filefield

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue and have been searching for an answer everywhere to no avail.

I'm assuming you're using a `ModelForm` but if not this should still mostly make sense. It appears that if the `clean_<field_name>()` function doesn't return anything then Django will do nothing with the existing `FileField` on the model in question.

In order to apply the clean function correctly if the file is changed, you should first perform the check `if file and not isinstance(file, FieldFile)`. This means that a file already saved to the Model will not be repeatedly checked if the form is saved again, while a new file will be checked for compliance.

Then the problem with the `clear` checkbox is that the data returned by the form to the function if the box is checked is simply `False` meaning that the logic in the clean function is bypassed and nothing is returned. For now, my temporary fix for the problem is as follows:

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models.fields.files import FieldFile


def clean_profile_picture(self):
    file = self.cleaned_data["profile_picture"]
    if file and not isinstance(file, FieldFile):
        content_type = file.content_type
        if content_type in ['image/jpeg', 'image/png']:
            # Reject files that don't match whitelisted content types
            raise forms.ValidationError("File type is not allowed (Allowed types: jpeg, png).")
        return file
    elif not file:
        # If 'clear' checkbox is checked, blank the FieldFile
        return False
```

I expect that this does *not* catch for a number of possible error cases but it will effectively clear the `FileField` on the model. Note that the condition uses `FieldFile`, not `FileField` - this is intentional. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#filefield-and-fieldfile). You might also find that the `content_type` check I use is more appropriate as it will catch files with odd or incorrect file extensions.

Hope this goes someway to help.